# Cannot run 32 bit executables on a 64 bit system

Tags: arch-linux, 64bit, 32bit, architecture

I've been pulling my hair out for days trying to run a 32 bit binary on a 64 bit arch installation.  When I do try to run it, using `./scarlet`, I get this:

```
bash: ./scarlet: no such file or directory
```

and it's driving me insane.  I've tried to install `libstdc++`, and a bunch of others, but none seem to work.  However, when I do install `libstdc++`, I get a new error:

```
./scarlet: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So it seems that I'm missing whatever package holds the library `libstdc++.so.6`.  A simple web search would point to all of the packages that I've already installed, and none of them work.  I primarily use Arch, but I would be fine with answers pointing towards Fedora as well.  So how do I fix this?

output of `ldd scarlet`

```
linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7efa000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libGL.so.1 => not found
    libX11.so.6 => not found
    libXrandr.so.2 => not found
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => not found
    libXi.so.6 => not found
    libXcursor.so.1 => not found
    libXinerama.so.1 => not found
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf7e13000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7dee000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf7c01000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7efc000)
```

Thanks.

### Update

After installing a bunch of stuff:

```
sudo dnf install libstdc++.i686 libX11.i686 libXrandr.i686  ibXxf86vm.i686 libXi.i686 libXcursor.i686 libXinerama.i686
```

I now get a new error that I'm missing the library `libGL.so.1`
I've tried to:

```bash
sudo dnf install libGL.i686 #and just the standard libGL, but it's already installed
```

but no luck, because Fedora can't find the package.

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:33:42 ago on Fri 26 Aug 2022 09:51:02 AM EDT.
No match for argument: libGL.i686
Error: Unable to find a match: libGL.i686
```

Comment: What does `ldd scarlet` show?

Comment: I fail to understand how the error messages you get make you believe that your system is getting problems running 32 bits executables. Any other attempt ?

Comment: It's a 32 bit binary that I'm trying to run, but the 64 bit version runs fine.  @StephenKitt I've updated the question to show `ldd scarlet`

Comment: @Zany_Zachary1, do you have 32bit libraries installed?

Comment: as with any other executable, you'll need to install (and have available for your dynamic linker) all the libraries it uses, in the same architecture as the executable. Your scarlet in its 64 bit version wouldn't run, either, had you not, say, libXi.so.6 in the 64 bit version. So, you'll need to figure which dependencies the program uses, enable arch's `[multilib]` package sources, and install the 32bit versions of the dependencies.

Comment: I don’t know how to fix this on Arch, but the `ldd` output tells you what you need to fix: every “not found” library needs to be installed (in its 32-bit variant).

Comment: I installed all the packages that were not found, but a new problem has arisen: the LibGL.so.1 library. (edited question)

Comment: Did you have `lib32-gcc-libs` installed on Arch?

Comment: It's `mesa-libGL.i686` and `libglvnd.i686`.

Comment: You can search which packages provides something (in this case LibGL.so.1) by doing `dnf provides something` . My guess is that you haven't installed the 32-bit (i686) package yet.